# ASP.net Change Password Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a eCommerce project which has an admin panel and shopping panels.

I have finished programming and now testing every single aspx and cs files by manually.

The problem is, I have a change password feature which is related with session and Database. The problem is I have a validators in my aspx file but they won't work. Here my codes are;

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnChange">
        <div class="userForm">
            <div class="formTitle">
                Change Your Password
            </div>
            <div class="formContent">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" placeholder="Type your new password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                    ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="signup">Enter a password</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgainPassword" placeholder="Repeat your new password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" BorderColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtAgainPassword" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter password again."
                    ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="signup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="txtPassword"
                    ControlToValidate="txtAgainPassword" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Password don't match."
                    ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="signup"></asp:CompareValidator>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnChange" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnChange_Click" />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblError" Visible="False" ForeColor="Green" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

and the .cs part is below

```
protected void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ZirveMarketDBEntities context = new ZirveMarketDBEntities())
    {
        // Atanan sessiona gore user bilgisini al - guvenlik icin onemli
        int id = (int)Session["CustomerID"];
        Customer cust = context.Customers.Where(i => i.CustomerID == id).FirstOrDefault();

        cust.Password = txtPassword.Text;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    lblError.Visible = true;
    lblError.Text = "Password successfully updated";
}
```

The problem is, I have a 2 box for new password and type new password. Even if they are null, even if they don't match the password still changes with the value of the first part. I don't want to run server side code if they don't match or null. What am I doing wrong? Helps are pretty apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the 'ValidationGroup="signup"' attribute to the btnChange button.

I'd also recommend adding the below to the click event (before anything else) in case Javascript is disabled on the client:

```
Page.Validate("signup");

if (!Page.IsValid)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ah, How could I miss that! Seems its time to take a break for me :) Thanks for the answer, I will also consider your recommend on each buttons I use, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this. For some reason when using placeholders w/ asp TextBox controls, the required validator would not work in IE9 and 8. Adding this code to btn submit event fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You have validation groups specified on the validators, but not on the Button. Try adding the validation group to the button as well.